# Swift - segue programmatically takes two seconds to show view controller the first time

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I can't find why a segue programmatically takes about 2 seconds to show the view controller the first time. When I return to the view controller and try to perform the segue again, it doesn't take time to show the view controller. These view controllers I have opened from a modal segue.

I'm doing something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("<segue identifier>", sender: indexPath)
    }
}
```

And for the `UITableView` I disabled the `delaysContentTouches` option. And it still doesn't work, it just takes about two seconds to open, but only the first time.

Meanwhile I have an `NSTimer` fetching data from a web service, but I read that `NSTimer` executes on a different thread, so I think this is not the problem.

Am I missing something to make the segue show the view controller faster?

Comment: Check what thread you are on when this method is called. You should already me on the main thread, so there is no need for your GCD call, which can slow you down.

Comment: Are you using any custom fonts?  Does it display the keyboard for the first time in your app?  Do you see the same delay when not running under the xcode debugger?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am using a custom font and it doesn't display the keyboard for the first time. I realized the delay is only when I run the app under the xcode debugger

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer can work on a background thread but does not necessarily do so.  It depends on how you instantiate it.   A simple repeating timer would typically use the main thread's runLoop which is closely tied to UI updates.  That being said, I doubt that your timer could cause a delay in showing the view. It is more likely that some heavy processing is being performed while the UI is setting up.

The typical things that could induce such a one-time delay are:
- A large image on the view (in the  storyboard or Nib)
- Giving firstResponder to a text field that needs to show the on-screen keyboard (the on-screen keyboard always takes a couple of seconds to show up the first time)
- Complex UI constraints that make auto-layout go through multiple passes to figure out the positions and sizes of subviews (but that would reoccur the next time around unless you're keeping the view controller alive and reusing it).
- Repeated reload on a UITableView or UICollectionView (this may happen if you're trying to show the data as it comes in) but this would also reoccur on subsequent calls to the segue unless you're caching something